# Стоит ли использовать везде GraphQL?

Tags: node.js, graphql

предыдущий проект реализовал методом REST API, контроллеры, роуты. В новом проекте решил использовать GraphQL. Понравился query который может быстро и легко доставать нужные данные. Но вот вопрос надо ли теперь использовать его везде? К примеру для получения продуктов он отлично подходит. А к примеру для добавления продуктов, регистрации пользователей мне показалось удобнее использовать REST API. К примеру для авторизации где требуется middleware .

Как по мне для мутации он не так подходит. Вопрос стоит ли его использовать везде или только для получения сложных запросов. Вопрос может и странный ибо никаких ограничений в этом плане нет, но сколько докладов я смотрел везде отказывались о REST API в пользу Graphql.